# Angular and jQuery Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have some problems with Angular and jQuery that does an http call to api in rest in an a WebServlet. I would like print result of request in HTML Page with ng-show but, I can't- 
This is my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', []);
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.chiliSpicy = function() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/RESTnt/";
    var user = "admin";
    var pwd = "password";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + 'login?username='+user+'&password='+pwd,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data)
            {
                $scope.result = true;
            },
        error: function (data) 
            {
                $scope.result = false;
            },
        async:true
        });
    };
}])
```

and this is my html

```
<html>
```

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="spicyApp1">
<div ng-controller="SpicyController">
 <button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">Chili</button>
 <p>The food is {{spice}} spicy!</p>
 <p ng-show="result===200" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is higher.</p>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="ajaxQuery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the angular way to do `ajax` calls using [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Can you give more details than "I can't"? Also, since you're using jQuery, angular doesn't know about the `success` and `error` callback functions, so a digest cycle doesn't run afterward. (i.e., the changes won't show until you change something else on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid mixing jQuery methods and AngularJS methods. Angular has its own ajax service called [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), which you could use:

```
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(url + 'login?username='+user+'&password='+pwd).success(function(data) {
        $scope.result = true;
    })
}
```

If you insist on using jQuery ajax, you can do this by adding a `$scope.$apply()` to you response callbacks:

```
    success: function(data)
        {
            $scope.result = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
    error: function (data) 
        {
            $scope.result = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
```

This is required to tell angular that the scope has been changed and to run the [digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) which will check the HTML DOM for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ajax call success, write the following code:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.result = true;
});`
```